# Intellij IDEA ColdFusion SQL autocomplete

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, autocomplete, intellij-idea, coldfusion-10

I am using Intellij IDEA with ColdFusion applications. The database/datasource is loaded, and the connection was successful(tested). I'm using MySQL, with the default drivers set by intellij IDEA.

I am trying to use a `<cfquery>` and Intellij IDEA doesn't seem to be picking up the autocomplete. When I type the name of a table or field in my database it does not suggest that name. It seems to only be using generalized SQL instead of autocomplete. How do I turn this on, or get this to work with ColdFusion?

Comment: Autocomplete usually requires javascript to make an ajax call to a database to get values to offer to the user.  I see by the tag data that intellij-idea is an IDE.  When you did what you did, was any code written that you could see?

Comment: Yes, <cfquery> is a coldfusion tag that calls for a query on the database specified such as <cfquery datasource="learncfinaweek">. The basic functionality of this code would prompt intellij idea to display my queries as I type in statement such as SELECT name. However in my case when I type SELECT it does not prompt me with a list of options for autocomplete.

Comment: Autocomplete is a UI feature. One that existed in IDEs long before forms/browsers had it (for that matter it existed there before everyone went ajax mad, and is probably still most common as non-ajax functionality of the address bar). Anways, the issue Ryan is having is that Intellij Idea has a feature where it autocompletes table/column names, but it's not working for him. Nothing to do with code being generated; it's presumably a setup/config issue of some sort.

Comment: You might need to try something with [language injections](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-language-injections.html) - however I couldn't get that working (even with other languages) - the docs didn't match with what I'm seeing, so might be for a different version.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the ColdFusion plugin for IntelliJ has a way for you to specify the databases or ColdFusion data sources used, you will not be able to get this kind of 'code assist'. Even ColdFusion builder needs you to add information about your server, and have RDS turned on, in order to handle offer 'code assist' for queries.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply Scott. I assure you that the database has been defined. In Intellij there is a tab called database where it allows you to connect directly to the data sources that you're using. I can open that database connection, and run queries from within the sql browser, which let's me know that the ide is in fact connected to the data source. However when I try to use auto complete within my <cfqueries> it does not give me hints from the database that I have been using.

Comment: When you use `<cfquery>` IntelliJ has no idea what database you are to which you are trying to connect - only to which data source - yes you can use attributes like `server` in `<cfquery>`, but I doubt the IntelliJ ColdFusion plugin is smart enough to handle that. Connecting to the database via the IDE is different than connecting to a ColdFusion data source. Yes, they are VERY similar, but they are different.

Comment: So how would i make the proper connection ?

Comment: Using IntelliJ? You can't, not the way you want to.

Comment: The feature is talked about everywhere, and is offered in every code except cold fusion, even with php. I believe it may be a setting, or something I have to turn on.

Comment: _"I doubt the IntelliJ ColdFusion plugin is smart enough to handle that"_ - matching a datasource attribute from a cfquery tag is **easy** - and even if it wasn't, IntelliJ IDEA does plenty of actually complicated things, so there's no reason it can't do this.

Comment: I downloaded it earlier and opened a file with a cfquery in; then there was a thing that prompted me to setup a datasource (suggesting this feature _is_ implemented), but I couldn't figure out the correct JDBC syntax to use for MS SQL Server (the only database I had available) and didn't have time to investigate properly.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I began my initial response with a disclaimer about needing to configure this. Matching a data source attribute in a cfquery tag is easy....knowing what database is being referenced by that data source is not as easy, if there is no way for IntelliJ to know what database to which the data source refers.

Comment: Instead of guessing at what IDEA can or cannot do, and using disclaimers and qualifications in case your guesses are wrong, why not actually check what it can do? Knowing what database is being referenced _is_ easy: You ask the developer to tell you. **This is what IntelliJ IDEA does.** When you have a query and no datasource setup, it specifically prompts _"No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance."_

Comment: [IDEA supports SQL autocomplete](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html) - again, it specifically says _"All features IntelliJ IDEA provides for SQL are also available for SQL embedded into other languages."_ and it knows about datasources, and it tells you it can provbide "advanced code assistance" if a datasource is setup - everything IntelliJ IDEA needs is available - the OPs issue is simply figuring out some missing piece of configuration that makes it actually work.

Comment: Which is what I said in my answer -"Unless the ColdFusion plugin for IntelliJ has a way for you to specify the databases or ColdFusion data sources used, you will not be able to get this kind of 'code assist'." Only, it seems this is not specific to the ColdFusion plugin.

Comment: Apparently, it did *NOT* prompt the OP to provide database information, or else they would not have had a need to post.

Comment: Hey, Scott and Peter... are you perhaps talking at cross purposes? Scott talking about ColdFusion DSNs, and Peter about IntelliJ IDEA ones? Perhaps a case in point that demonstrates this is Peter was talking about doing the JDBC config, whereas if it was integrating properly into ColdFusion, it'd read that from the CF DSN?

Comment: I just opened a file in IntelliJ and created a `cfquery` block and was NOT prompted to enter database information. I opened a file that had `cfquery` in it and was NOT prompted for database information.

Comment: Do I need to provide a screenshot of the prompt? :/ Datasource setup is one step (which the OP has stated they did), not the entire solution. Based on looking into what IDEA provides, it seems something regarding language injections might also need to be done.

Comment: Adam, the SQL autocomplete is an existing feature, so whilst integrating into the config files for CF/Railo would be nice, it would also require more work from IntelliJ than just "this block is SQL; this attribute is the datasource" - which is (in theory) the only extra work supporting cfquery otherwise requires.